# User's login shown in a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a report card for students. Teachers come to a google sheet to select/type in a student's name (e.g., cell B5). Then the rest of the sheet shows what courses and scores that the student took.

Limitation: This is only good for instructors. I would also like to give students access to their own report card. I don't want them to see other students' data.

Question: Can I have cell B5 selected automatically, based on student's signin email? I think this requires a script. Could you please suggest where I should start?

Comment: Yes, this will require a script. I've done something similar before. You will also need to be a domain super administrator in order to use the directory service to identify the user. Note, that there will be a major privacy issue with this approach as all students will be using the same sheet and be able to see the scores of another student if they have the sheet open. A web app would be the best approach but a steep learning curve as its coding will be specific to your data structure.

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. Are you using regular Google accounts or G Suite accounts? This is important because there are restrictions about getting the login programatically. Bear in mind that in order to be able to run a script the user should have edit access.

Comment: 2 possible ways (assuming that there's a column with student's emails):
1st - a simple sheets add-on that would only import data pertaining to them via custom sheets menu
2nd - a simple HTML-based frontend web-app (might be an overkill)
Happy to help out with either :) Encountered a similar request recently on Twitter too - https://twitter.com/schoraria911/status/1204768072927592448

Comment: @JamesD Yes, it will take me forever to learn the coding.

Comment: @Rubén I use G Suite accounts. I don't think I state my question clear enough. The process I imagine is the script will run when the sheet is opened. When the login has edit permission, the script won't be run. When the login has view-only permission, the script will look for the email/login and change B5 to the person's email/login. Is this possible? Completely novice here. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not possible because scripts only run for editors, not for viewers.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria Yes, all help is appreciated. The process I described to Rubén might not work at all. Which add-on would you recommend? I'm more interested in the Html-based solution, just because my school might not allow me use an add-on at all. Could you please point me in a direction? Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Rubén Got it. That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The HTML based frontend solution is a total customised buiild. I have a little too much of a free time till the end of this year and can build one based on your requirements - no charge :)

Comment: @SourabhChoraria It would be amazing if you could do that. What does student's experience like?

Comment: @DianaT - since this may not be directly related to what you had originally wanted, I've posted my solution here - https://script.gs/display-user-specific-spreadsheet-data-on-a-web-app/ - do please let me know if that works for you and please feel free to DM me in case you require any help setting it up :) I'm at `code@script.gs`

Comment: @SourabhChoraria Thank you so much! I will let you know how it goes. I really appreciate your help on this!